# MongoID where queries map_reduce association

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mongoid

I have an application who is doing a job aggregating data from different Social Network sites Back end processes done Java working great. 
Its front end is developed Rails application deadline was 3 weeks for some analytics filter abd report task still few days left almost completed. 
When i started implemented map reduce for different states work great over 100,000 record over my local machine work great.
Suddenly my colleague gave me current updated database which 2.7 millions record now my expectation was it would run great as i specify date range and filter before map_reduce execution. My believe was it would result set of that filter but its not a case.

Example
I have a query just show last 24 hour loaded record stats

result comes 0 record found but after 200 seconds with 2.7 million record before it comes in milliseconds..
CODE EXAMPLE BELOW

```
filter is hash of condition expected to check before map_reduce
map function
reduce function
SocialContent.where(filter).map_reduce(map, reduce).out(inline: true).entries
```

Suggestion please.. what would be ideal solution in remaining time frame as database is growing exponentially in days.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look at a few different things:

- Does all your data still fit in memory? You have a lot more records now, which could mean that MongoDB needs to go to disk a lot more often.
- M/R can not make use of indexes. You have not shown your Map and Reduce functions so it's not possible to point out mistakes. Update the question with those functions, and what they are supposed to do and I'll update the answer.
- Look at using the Aggregation Framework instead, it can make use of indexes, and also run concurrently. It's also a lot easier to understand and debug. There is information about it at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/